# Unable to use ndk-gdb

Tags: android, ndk-gdb

when i run ndk-gdb in cgywin i get error saying "make: command not found" and "the device does not support the applications targetted CPU abi's"

```
$ ndk-gdb --verbose --nowait
Android NDK installation path: /cygdrive/c/Android/ndk
Using default adb command: /cygdrive/c/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
ADB version found: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31
Using ADB flags:
Using JDB command:
Using auto-detected project path: .
Found package name: com.example.mygame
/cygdrive/c/Android/ndk/ndk-gdb: line 120: make: command not found
ABIs targetted by application:
Device API Level: 10
Device CPU ABIs: armeabi-v7a armeabi
ERROR: The device does not support the application's targetted CPU ABIs!
       Device supports:  armeabi-v7a armeabi
       Package supports:
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    c:/cocos2d-x/external/Box2D

LOCAL_MODULE := mygame
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static box2d_static 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    b2DebugDraw.cpp \
    Box2DRenderer.cpp \
    Main.cpp \
    InGameScreen.cpp 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-add-path, c:/cocos2d-x) 
$(call import-add-path, c:/cocos2d-x/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt)
$(call import-module, cocos2dx)
$(call import-module, external/Box2D)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_OPTIM:= debug
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1 -std=c++11 -Wno-literal-suffix -g
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8
```

im using a kindle fire with 2.3.3 installed

Answer (score 0):

The obvious first answer is that make.exe (GNU Make) needs to be in your path. Is it installed in Cygwin? Check the Cygwin installer.